# Avoiding big reference data in unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, testing

I would like to write a unit test for the correctness of a function that computes a relatively large amount of data, e.g.,

```
A = compute_that_matrix()
```

I could now compute the matrix once, make sure the result is correct, store the raw data as reference data, and then test against it:

```
Aref = read_reference_data('reference.dat')
A = compute_that_matrix()
assert(norm(A - Aref) < 1.0e-13)
```

This however requires me to ship the binary blob `reference.dat` which seems less than ideal.

What are other common ways of asserting the correctness of functions like `compute_that_matrix()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the test you gave would do the job of locking down the code against inadvertent breaking changes, it's less than ideal because it doesn't say anything about the result. The reference data doesn't mean anything to the reader of the test.

That test may also overconstrain your result. There might be code changes that you could make that would make your code clearer or faster that would incidentally change the result by an inconsequential amount, or change an element by a lot that you don't care about at all, but that test will forbid such changes.

You were somehow able to "make sure the result is correct". How did you do that? **Whatever you did to check the result manually, write unit tests to check that.** Your tests will then actually say something useful -- will describe the algorithm to some degree, and they'll only constrain what they need to constrain.

Comment: I agree with your overall point, but want to suggest that "overconstraining" the result is something I would *expect* from a test like this. If I'm making changes to the code to make it clearer, [I shouldn't be changing any behavior](http://martinfowler.com/articles/workflowsOfRefactoring/ "Martin Fowler - Workflows of Refactoring"). (I would argue the same for optimizations, but leniently.) Most importantly, accidentally changing a result by an "inconsequential amount" could potentially be **disastrous** - particularly if I'm dealing with floating point precision and roundoff errors.

Comment: Good catch! In fact, right now I'm not testing for correctness, only for the fact that the never changes. To think about what makes the reference results correct requires some thinking, but it probably the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

If reducing the matrix is not an option, shipping the correct answer as a data blob (or even inlined into the testing code) seems like a reasonable thing to do.

If you are lucky, you can find and implement an independent second method of calculating the correct answer. The challenge then is that there are two different code bases to debug in case of a test failure.